# Dojox Datagrid : event when a column is resized?

Tags: datagrid, dojo, resize

I'm using Dojox Datagrid and I want to know if it's possible to capture a column resizing event.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I believe Dojo's Grids (DataGrid is just an extension of Grid), have an onResizeColumn event you can listen to with dojo/on. The API for DataGrid can be found here: http://dojotoolkit.org/api/?qs=1.9/dojox/grid/DataGrid